# How do you get a std::list to allocate memory for n amount of objects in C++?

Tags: c++, list, std

My goal is to have a std::list that allocates enough memory for the objects I will put in it, so I do not have to deal with potential exceptions when it expands, or the extra time needed for it to expand.

My first try involves splicing from a wave table:

```
std::list<T> list();
        auto listI = list.begin;
        typename std::list<T>::iterator waveStart = waveTable.begin();
        for(int i = 0; i < waveIndex; i++) {
            waveStart++;
        }
        typename std::list<T>::iterator waveEnd;
        int tCounter = nSamples;
        while(tCounter > 0) {
            if(tCounter > (waveTable.size() - waveIndex)) {
                waveEnd = waveStart;
                for(int i = 0; i < (waveTable.size() - waveIndex); i++) {
                    waveEnd++;
                }
                tCounter = (tCounter - (waveTable.size() - waveIndex));
            } else {
                waveEnd = waveStart;
                for(int i = 0; i < tCounter; i++) {
                    waveEnd++;
                }
                tCounter = 0;
            }
            list.splice(listI, waveTable, waveStart, waveEnd);
            waveStart = waveTable.begin();
        }

        phase += (tp * frequency * (nSamples/sampleRate));
        while(phase > tp) {
            phase -= tp;
        }
        waveIndex = (phase / tp) * waveTable.size();
```

I was planning to copy the values, but splice removed the values from the waveTable, so I am going to use insert.

The problem is, insert increases the size of the list and I can not find a way to tell the list how much memory it will need to hold all the values I want to store in it.

Answer (score 2):

> My goal is to have a std::list that allocates enough memory for the objects I will put in it

Okay, seems reasonable. You can do this by calling the appropriate constructor as @Gyross mentioned.

> so I do not have to deal with potential exceptions when it expands

Now this is where your question stops making sense. If you are out of memory, surely preallocating won't fix things. Also depending on your type, it can still potentially throw exceptions when the copy (or in some cases) move assignment function is called by you (when using `node = newvalue`).

> or the extra time needed for it to expand

It is ironic that you are using `std::list` and care about performance this much, since it is one of if not the slowest container in the standard library. If you want a high performance fixed container I recommend writing/using a ringbuffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify initial size in the constructor, with `std::list<T> list_obj(n)`.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list

There's also `std::list::resize`.

Comment: But then insert increases the size

Comment: insert will always increase the size, instead of doing `list.insert(it, val)`, do `*it = val`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at implementing a custom allocator.

The full requirements for a custom allocator class is here
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

The below example allocator always allocates `num_items` elements on the stack, and throws `std::bad_alloc()` if the number of elements exceeds the statically defined size.

You may want to move away from the stack using `new` `delete` or similar to avoid overflows if you have a lot of elements.

```
template<typename T, size_t num_items>
class MyAllocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using void_pointer = std::nullptr_t;
    using const_void_pointer = const std::nullptr_t;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    /* should copy assign the allocator when copy assigning container */
    using propagate_on_container_copy_assignment = std::true_type;

    /* should move assign the allocator when move assigning container */
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;

    /* should swap the allocator when swapping the container */
    using propagate_on_container_swap = std::true_type;

    /* two allocators does not always compare equal */
    using is_always_equal = std::false_type;

    MyAllocator() : m_index(0) {};
    ~MyAllocator() noexcept = default;

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind {
        using other = MyAllocator<U, num_items>;
    };

    [[nodiscard]] pointer allocate(size_type n) {
        if (m_index+n >= num_items)
            throw std::bad_alloc();

        pointer ret = &m_buffer[m_index];
        m_index += n;
        return ret;

    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
        (void) p;
        (void) n;
        /* do nothing */
    }

    size_type max_size() {
        return num_items;
    }


    bool operator==(const MyAllocator& other) noexcept {
        /* storage allocated by one allocator cannot be freed by another */
        return false;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MyAllocator& other) noexcept {
        /* storage allocated by one allocator cannot be freed by another */
        return !(*this == other);
    }

private:
    value_type m_buffer[num_items];
    size_t m_index;
};
```

And then you can use

```
constexpr size_t always_allocate_this_amount_of_elements = 10;
std::list<int, MyAllocator<int, always_allocate_this_amount_of_elements>> list;
```

Comment: I don't think you can store the values directly inside the allocator like this, I think the state needs to be in an external pool...

Comment: I think there is support for a stateful allocator if the == operators does not always compare equal. But I recommend moving away from the stack anyways